# Find if's with no following curly braces with Visual Studio regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I'm using the find feature of Visual Studio with regular expressions to find if's in my code where there's no following curly braces. I came up with `if\ .*\).*\n.*{` to find if's where there are curly braces and it works. So similarly, I tried to use `if\ .*\).*\n.*[^{]`, but it just returns all the if's in the code. Can someone explain why this happens?

**Edit:**
The pattern I'm trying to match is

```
if (someCondition)
{ // <- Spot if there is a curly brace here
    ...
}
```

Comment: @AyushGupta 1- I'm not using javascript. 2- I actually want to fix the if's hence why I'm trying to find them with the find/regex with visual studio. 3- Why the question mark?

Comment: Try [`\bif .*\).*[\r\n]+\s*[^\s{]`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbif+.*%5c%29.*%5b%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%5cs*%5b%5e%5cs%7b%5d&i=if+%28someCondition%29%0d%0a++++wh+%3d+fg%3b%0d%0aif+%28someCondition%29+%0d%0a%7b%0d%0a++++wh+%3d+fg%3b%0d%0a%7d)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks it worked. It also makes a lot of sense to detect the first character that is not a curly brace AND a whitespace character on the second line.

Comment: I posted a bit modified version with explanations, just in case you want to tweak it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to match `if` at the start of a line (or after whitespace) that is followed with a space and any 0+ chars followed with `)` at the end of the line, and then the next line should start with any char but whitespace and `{` you may use

```
^\s*if .*\)\s*[\r\n]+\s*[^\s{]
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5Cs*if%20.*%5C%29%5Cs*%5B%5Cr%5Cn%5D%2B%5Cs*%5B%5E%5Cs%7B%5D&i=if%20%28someCondition%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20wh%20%3D%20fg%3B%0D%0Aif%20%28someCondition%29%20%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20wh%20%3D%20fg%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aif%20%28someCondition%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20wh%20%3D%20fg%3B%0D%0A%7D).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces (note that in VS search and replace regex flavor, it does not match line breaks)
- `if .*\)` - `if`, space, any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then a `)`
- `\s*[\r\n]+\s*` - 1+ line break(s) enclosed with optional (0 or more) whitespace chars
- `[^\s{]` - any char but a whitespace or `{`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change your logic and use `^` and `$` - the start and end symbols of a line from `regex` syntax. Read more about it [here.](https://regexone.com/lesson/line_beginning_end)

I see you are looking for lines which starts with `if` and ends without `{`

```
if (var name){
}

if (var name)
```

so you want second if, not the first.

REGEX : `if \([\w]+ [\w]+\)$`

Check demo [here.](https://regexr.com/3mfsq)

Comment: I added an edit. Following your logic I would still need to see if the first character of the next after ```^``` is __not__ a curly brace. Which basically comes down to what I came up with, am I wrong? Also I have no gurantee on the number of tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you make wild assumptions about code formatting and limiting syntax, this search is too complex for regex.

No matter how fancy this regex gets (they can get pretty darned fancy :-), it will never be fancy enough, because the syntax is context free, which is beyond the power of regex.

Grab a yacc file for C (or C99) grammar ... (no promises, but there is one at http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y-2011.html), and look at the structure of a selection_statement (i.e. IF '(' expression ')' ...).

There may be tools for this, but you roll the dice with regex.

Comment: We're in the process of linting our code. We're basically using google's code guidelines. So we'll have to integrate their cpplint.py in our pipeline someday for sure. But for now this'll have to do.